# Why do these two graphs intersect at 0.618 (golden ratio)?

Tags: golden-ratio

I was playing around with Desmos Graphing Calculator and found that the two graphs below intersect at (-1,0), (0,-1), **(1.618, 1.618)**, and **(-0.618, -0.618)**. The latter two points are the golden ratio and the negative of the golden ratio plus 1.

Graphs:

- $y = x^2 - 1$
- $x = y^2 - 1$

Why do the graphs intersect at these points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $x = (x^2-1)^2 -1 \iff x+1 = (x^2-1)^2 \iff x^4 - 2x^2 - x = 0$ so $$x(x^3 - 2x - 1) = x(x+1)(x^2-x-1) =0$$ so the roots are $x=0,-1, \phi, -\phi^{-1}$ by using the quadratic formula on the last term.

Comment: Is the last term ($−ϕ^−1$) is -0.618...? The properties of the golden ratio keep surprising me!

Comment: @TimK It's the negative of the inverse of $\phi$

Comment: @Omry, yes I understand the notation. I was just surprised.

Comment: @TimK $1+\frac{1}{\phi}=\phi$

Comment: @Omry, do people know why that this number has so many of these kind of properties?

Comment: @TimK That last property is just what you get from taking $x^2-x-1=0$, transferring the $-x-1$ to the other side of the equation, and dividing by x. Nothing special about $\phi$ in this one.